# CSS Blend all edges of a <div>

Tags: html, blur, css, blending

Can I blend a div the way I am wanting to? I understand I can use

```
body {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px white;
}
```

to get close, but what I'd like it to do is blend all edges (top, bottom, left, right) equally. The box-shadow seems to really only blend 3 sides, giving the 3D effect. I'm not really interest in the 3D, just want all my edges to blend into the background photo.

Help, friends!

Answer (score 2):

Just read what are you applying "10px 10px 10px 10px" to..

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

You are giving 10px and 10px to HORIZONTAL and VERTICAL offset, that's why you get the 3d effect.

Just remove them:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px white;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wAcC6/

ex.

Answer (score 1):

See http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/ and http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/
You have remove vertical and horizontal offsets

http://jsfiddle.net/d552b/

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0 0 20px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0 0 20px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

Explanation of the components of box-shadow

1. **The horizontal offset** of the shadow, positive means the shadow will
   be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on
   the left of the box.
2. **The vertical offset** of the shadow, a negative
   one means the box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means
   the shadow will be below the box.
3. **The blur radius** (optional), if set
   to 0 the shadow will be sharp, the higher the number, the more
   blurred it will be.
4. **The spread radius** (optional), positive values
   increase the size of the shadow, negative values decrease the size.
   Default is 0 (the shadow is same size as blur).
5. **Color**